# EC Public key from public key bytes extracted from azure keyvault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, public-key, ecdsa

how to get public key from bytes? for example, I have public key (generated with EC algorithm, curve "secp256r1") and its encoded bytes on java, How can I create public key from these bytes in c#?

Comment: What do you mean "public key"? Is that you want to know how to get Azure Key Vault    key?

Comment: yes, I stored one certificate inside the azure vault and i used that certificate to sign the self created jwt-token using signasync method. I want to extract the public key from the same certificate to verify the signatures of signed token

Comment: Is that you want to export cer file from Azure key vault?

Comment: No. I don't want to export any file from the key vault.

Comment: I am using the getKeyAsync method to fetch the key from vault and I am getting the ky bundle from the vault. Inside the bundle key is in byte array so i wanted to convert the byte array to get correct key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different methods to fetch the key from the vault. I used the following for the same.

```
var secret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(vaultAddress, "Honeywellpkiofflinetokenprime256v1cert").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 X509Certificate2Collection exportedCertCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            exportedCertCollection.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value));


            X509Certificate2 certFromSecret = exportedCertCollection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Single(s => s.HasPrivateKey);
            var publickeybyte = certFromSecret.GetPublicKey();
            var publicekeybyte = certFromSecret.GetPublicKeyString();
            var PublicKeyCNG= certFromSecret.GetECDsaPublicKey();


            var privateECDsa = LoadPrivateKey(FromHexString(privateKey));
            var publiccECDsa = LoadPublicKey(FromHexString(publicKey));
```

now you can use the same key to verify your signed information.